# HTML <select> not submitted

Tags: php, html, forms, post

I'm trying to submit a form to my PHP validation script and I get 2 undefined indexes. Both of which are an select tag (school and function, focus on the function for this question). I've looked through several posts, and I still don't see what's wrong.

Here's the form:

```
<form action="actions/user_edit.php?id='. $user['id'] .'" method="post" id="form_editUser" class="col s12">
   <div class="row">
      <div class="input-field col s12">
         <input value="'.$user['name'].'" id="name" name="name" type="text" class="validate">
         <label for="name">Naam</label>
      </div>
      <div class="input-field col s12">
         <input value="'.$user['email'].'" id="email" name="email" type="text" class="validate">
         <label for="email">Email</label>
      </div>
      <div class="input-field col s12">
         <select id="school" name="school">
            <option>Ignore this select kthxbai
            <option>
         </select>
         <label>School</label>
      </div>
      <div class="input-field col s12">
         <select id="function" name="function">
            <option value="" disabled>Kies functie</option>
            <option value="Admin" >Admin</option>
            <option value="Directeur" >Directeur</option>
            <option value="Docent" >Docent</option>
         </select>
         <label>Functie</label>
      </div>
   </div>
</form>
<div class="modal-footer">
   <input type="submit" value="Bewerk" form="form_editUser" class="modal-action modal-close waves-effect waves-green btn">
   <a href="#!" class=" modal-action modal-close waves-effect waves-green btn-flat">Annuleer</a>
</div>
```

Here's the PHP script:

```
require '../config/db.php';
$userId = $_GET['id'];

$name =        mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST["name"]);
$email =       mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST["email"]);
$schoolId =    mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST["school"]);
$function =    mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST["function"]);
```

Comment: Can you post the full errors ? Also, what `var_dump($_POST)` gives you when you post the form ?

Comment: Full error: 
Notice: Undefined index: school in D:\folder\project\admin\actions\user_edit.php on line 8

Notice: Undefined index: function in D:\folder\project\admin\actions\user_edit.php on line 9 and var_dump: array(2) { ["name"]=> string(16) "nameOfPerson" ["email"]=> string(28) "emailOfPerson@mail,com" }

Comment: By the look of the quotes, it appears your form is in one giant echo. Try undo-ing that first, as there's very likely a quote problem somewhere. Just use inline php tags in your HTML where needed. It reads a lot easier and is less error-prone.

Comment: You do not have a submit button, but your code works for me perfectly. Consider posting your userId as a hidden POST field rather than as a GET field.

Comment: Dumb question - are you selecting anything from your select options ? Has happened with me sometimes, if you do not select any option, the parameter wasn't included in the POST request itself.

Comment: There is a submit button, i'll add it to post

Comment: Can you try changing "function" to something else, such as "role"? See if it makes any difference.

Comment: Doesn't make a difference, it's purely the select that is not working, when I remove the select and just make a normal input then the value is submitted

Comment: Why your **school** `option` tag is not closing `</option>`

Comment: ignore that, I edited on SO and didn't go too well

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/q/1132303/32453

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out my form was inside a tbody element, which is not allowed. Problem solved, thanks for all the help!

Answer (score 0):

Make sure to check your $_POST[] variables for existence, eg.

```
$option = isset($_POST['school']) ? $_POST['school'] : false;
if ($option) {
    $schoolId =    mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST["school"]);
}
```

I have seen cases where if nothing was selected as an option, the same is not included in the POST payload itself.

Comment: Why should `school` not be included in the `POST` array?

Comment: If you haven't selected any option - in such cases I have seen it not getting included in the POST array. Probably in this case if we could get to know the POST request itself using developer option from the browser - it would clear up things. But in general you should be checking against POST variables inside your backend code.

Comment: $_POST["function"] and "school" are both not set.

Comment: I think you're on the right lines here, but you need to explain to the folks here the difference between POST submitting a value of something or not submitting anything into the POST array

Comment: @s.wakker If $_POST[] variables are not set in your php code, please use `isset()` to check values (and avoid the error you are getting). I asked you another think - is this only happening when in your form you are not selecting any value from school dropdown ? What happens if you select a value and then submit your form.